# Setting up a unmanaged dedicated web server on CentOS 5.6

Tags: php, centos

I just bought my webserver with iweb and to be quite honest, I don't know how to setup a dedicated webserver properly.

I have been able to install httpd, php, mysql but it doesn't seem complete. Also, if I want to install the latest versions of php 5.3.6 using yum commands, how do I do that.

```
I need help with
->Installing php 5.3.6 along with apc
->Make sure it is compatible with the rest of the configuration
```

Other php, httpd config to speed up the php.
I was gonna ask how to setup nginx as proxy server, but I thought it would be better as a separate question.

Comment: Don't you mean php 5.3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

yum install php53 php53-mysql php-pear gcc

wget http://pecl.php.net/get/APC-3.1.9.tgz

tar zxf APC-3.1.9.tgz

cd APC-3.1.9;phpize

./configure --enable-apc

make && make install

Add APC Stanza to /etc/php.ini:

```
; APC Settings
extension= "apc.so"
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=64M
```

service httpd restart

HTH, but if you couldn't find this online you're probably in for a tough time administering this server...

Comment: could you provide me with some of your bookmarks that you use for reference?

Comment: also, i am having a problem installing other php plugins since they are want to use php-common and this installs php53-common

Comment: @Kuldeep I don't really have any bookmarks per se. A big part of systems administration is just slogging through (sometimes poor/misleading) online documentation and testing/altering for your particular environment. After many years you get a feel for what you should do even if the docs say something else. I'm afraid there's no magic bullet.

Comment: @Kuldeep Post a different question for your php-common issue

Comment: nice pointers. thanks. i am having a problem installing other php plugins since they are want to use php-common and your method installs php53-common

Comment: 1 up for the answer, just waiting for the response to the subquestion then i will proceed to accept it.

Comment: it wont let me upvote

Comment: You need at least [15 Rep](http://serverfault.com/faq#reputation) in order up vote.